# Error with php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have this code:

```
$text = "###12###hello###43###good###113###thefinalstring";
preg_match_all('/(.*?)###(\d*)###(.*?)/is', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

If I dump $matches, why there is not "thefinalstring" anywhere?
Where is the error in the regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is your goal, what do you exactly want to match?

Comment: (.*?)###(\d*)###(.*?)([a-zA-Z]*)..Is it solving your purpose?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? are seeking for thefinalstring only ?

Comment: i want to know every part of the string, that is interrupted by a ###number### (and there can be any kind of chars)

Comment: so you want "hello", "good" and "thefinalstring" as matched result?

Comment: Yes, the final goal is to replace ###id### with something else, recognizing the id. Maybe it would be more easier with a str_replace with regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
(.*?)###(\d*)###(.*?)([a-zA-Z]*)
```

Use this regex

Comment: mmm this work with only normal chars.. how can I say, all chars?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
$text = "###12###hello###43###good###113###thefinalstring";
preg_match_all('/###(\d*)###([^#]*)/is', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ###12###hello
            [1] => 12
            [2] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ###43###good
            [1] => 43
            [2] => good
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ###113###thefinalstring
            [1] => 113
            [2] => thefinalstring
        )

)
```

Comment: we are close.. if it finds a #, it break... I want to break only if it finds another ###number###

Comment: @OscarFanelli: Sorry, I don't get you. You could show sample strings and what you want to match for each of them.

Comment: Sample 1: <p>Hello###405### </p><p>###32### </p>
Sample 2: ###403### Hello
Sample 3: Hello ###420001###
Sample 4: <div>Bye</div>